# Should 2 executables compiled from the same source at different times have the same MD5SUM?

Tags: md5, code-formatting

Should 2 executables compiled from the same source at different times have the same MD5SUM?

I have been evaluating Automated Code Formatting using Artistic Style.

One test I did was:

1. Do a Clean Compile
2. MD5SUM the executables
3. Clean the build directory out.
4. Run Astyle formatter on the code
5. Recompile the code.
6. MD5Sum the executables

My theory was that the MD5SUMs should match if there was no functional change to the code, but the MD5SUMs did not match.  Is there something wrong with my assumption, or did running ArtisticStyle (which should only change Whitespace) cause a semantic difference in my executable?

**EDIT:** If MD5Sums won't work, can anyone recommend a way to "prove" that the two executables are equivalent?

Comment: Technically the two executables are NOT equivalent. They are each the product of compilation at a different time.

Comment: I just rebuilt a C++ binary in Xcode and it's MD5 appears unchanged

Answer (score 3):

Binaries are likely to contain at least different time-stamps. So, no, two subsequent builds  from the same codebase will very likely produce different binaries. Functionally same, most probably same size and even same code, but md5 sums wouldn't match.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove is that the two are functionally equivalent so you'll need to review each of the changes in the binary file using a binary diff utility.  This will be a manual verification but if you find that the diffs are small in nature and timestamp related as Dmitry pointed out, then you can make the claim.